# The custom messages doesn't returned from FormRequest in my app based on Laravel 9.8.1

Tags: laravel, validation, request, message

Next is my FormRequest:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreFruitRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|string|min:3',
        'carbohydrates' => 'required|numeric|gte:0',
        'protein' => 'required|numeric|gte:0',
        'fat' => 'required|numeric|gte:0',
        'calories' => 'required|integer|numeric|gte:0',
        'sugar' => 'required|numeric|gte:0',
    ];
}

/**
 * Error Messages
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function messages() :array
{
    return [
        'carbohydrates.gte' => 'Nutrients cannot be negative',
        'protein.gte' => 'Nutrients cannot be negative',
        'fat.gte' => 'Nutrients cannot be negative',
        'calories.gte' => 'Nutrients cannot be negative',
        'sugar.gte' => 'Nutrients cannot be negative',
    ];
}
}
```

The validation rules work fine but when I make the request with the wrong value, which is a negative amount, validation does not return these messages to the controller. So, my API returns the main blade page as an error.

## **What is incorrect in my code? Or, do I need some tunings anywhere?**

Controller (as an answer for @NickSdot):

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param StoreFruitRequest $request
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function store(StoreFruitRequest $request)
{
    return response()->json(Fruit::create($request->all()) ?? "Cannot create fruit $request->name");
}
```

Comment: How does the controller look like?

Comment: *gte:field
The field under validation must be greater than or equal to the given field.*  but you are passing 0, wich is not a field. I think you should use `min:0` rule, wich accepts a value https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-min

Comment: I tried to change *gte:0* to *min:0*
The result is the same - the message is not used.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a middleware called ForceJsonResponse.php inside Middleware folder, and then add it to Kernel.php inside the $middleware variable.

ForceJsonResponse.php

```
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ForceJsonResponse
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [
   //your other classes
   \App\Http\Middleware\ForceJsonResponse::class,
];
```

Comment: Thank you! For that project, it's not already actual, but I'll try it for a new one.